# how to handle multiple radio buttons and their values - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so i have a problem where i have to handle some radio button which it comes from the mapped api json data

this is roughly what it looks like
[image: radiobtn]

The two radio buttons are in different groups, but when I select the value in the first radio button and switch to the second radio button, the value from the first radio button moves to the second radio button, so there is only 1 value even though the 2 radio buttons are in different groups.

For more details, I may attach a [live demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-ganguly-jpuxb)

my question how can i store the value of each radio button into an array? Thank you in advance

#UPDATE

i already fixed my problem, if anyone have the same problem u can check my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-bush-0ltx5)

Comment: Please provide your code! And don't link to something that doesn't have any relevance yet - edit to add the link when you have put something useful there - though it's preferred to put your code here on SO when possible.

Comment: @seesharper sorry i thought my codes is too long to show in here, so i put the external link to refer my codes

Answer (score 0):

You can have both the radio group values with the use of useEffect and useState hooks like this :

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [first, setFirst] = React.useState("");
  const [sec, setSec] = React.useState("");
  const [radioValues, setRadioValues] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const values = [];
    if (first.length) values[0] = first;
    if (sec.length) values[1] = sec;
    setRadioValues(values);
  }, [first, sec]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div onChange={(e) => setFirst(e.target.value)}>
        <input type="radio" value="Male" name="gender" /> Male
        <input type="radio" value="Female" name="gender" /> Female
      </div>
      <br></br>
      <div onChange={(e) => setSec(e.target.value)}>
        <input type="radio" value="Sunny" name="weather" /> Sunny
        <input type="radio" value="Cloudy" name="weather" /> Cloudy
      </div>
      {JSON.stringify(radioValues)}
      {JSON.stringify(first)}
      {JSON.stringify(sec)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you, but the number of radio group button is dynamically, so it can have 2 or more radio group button, so i think your solution cannot work to my codes

Comment: @ujuy you can copy and paste and edit the code as you wish please accept answer if it helped you in anyway